# Parse JSON response store value in variable

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm getting the following JSON response:

```
"Nitro": {
    "Login": {
        "sessionKey": "NHwxNDQ4MzR8MzY1ODE5ODMwMnwxMzQ0NzE5MTYyfDgxY2M1NjYxZDBiY2NiODI4NmM2Mjc1ODI2MzA1NDY3YmVhNzJjZDR8MA=="
    },
    "res": "ok",
    "method": "user.login",
    "server": "sbnitro01.prod.bunchball.net/nitro4.4.0"
}
}
```

I don't understand how to parse this with JavaScript and store the value of the sessionKey in a variable. I cannot use jQuery on this project and just cannot seem to get the key with JS.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: Where is this stored?  Where is this coming from?

Comment: The object that you have provided seems to be missing an intial '{'.  Is this by design or is the object larger than posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var sessionKey = obj.Nitro.Login['sessionKey'];
```

This takes the object that is stored in the `obj` variable, then takes the `Nitro` property object and then takes the `Login` property object and extracts the property `sessionKey` accordingly.